# How to draw a line in the chart?

Tags: pine-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsPAh.png)

As show in the image, the first three candles of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking basically about opening range.
This will take the time as input and will plot horizontal lines with the highs and lows of that period, so if you are on 15m TF and you want to get the higher high and lowest low of 3 candles, set it with a difference of a 45 min (15 * 3 = 45)...and so on.

It's not a square as your drawing, but it's what you asked.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script  - Opening range", overlay=true)

// Inputs
my_session = input("0930-1015", type=input.session, title='Custom Session')

FILL = input(true, title="Show Session BGcolor?")

// Determine if we are in a session
in_session = time(timeframe.period, my_session)
is_new_session(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

new_session = is_new_session("1440", my_session)

// Start of Session
is_newbar(res,sess) =>
    t = time(res,sess)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
new = (is_newbar("1440", my_session) ? 1 : 0)

// Plot Start Of Session
col_Start_of_Session = new_session and new==1? color.aqua:na
//plotshape(high, color=col_Start_of_Session, style=shape.circle, location= location.absolute, size=size.small, title="Start_of_Session")

// In Session High/Low Calculations
var float _low = close
var float _high = close

_low := new_session? low : in_session ? min(low, _low[1]) : na
_high := new_session  ? high : in_session ? max(high, _high[1]) : na

col_low = _low == low? na: true?color.red:na
col_high = _high== high? na:true? color.green:na

// Plot High/Low Line
Low=plot(_low, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=col_low)
High=plot(_high, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=col_high)

// BG Color
Fill_col = FILL ? color.new(color.yellow, 70):na
fill(Low,High, color=Fill_col)

// End of Session
start_of_session_value = valuewhen((new==1),high,0)
end_session_condition = start_of_session_value !=start_of_session_value[1]?0: in_session?1:0 
end_session = (end_session_condition == 0) and (end_session_condition[1]==1)? color.orange:na
//plotshape(close, color=end_session, location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.small)

// Extend High/Low Session Lines
v_extend_low = valuewhen((_low == low),low,0)
col_v_extend_low =  (end_session_condition == 0) and v_extend_low ==v_extend_low[1] ? color.red:na

v_extend_high = valuewhen((_high == high),high,0)
col_v_extend_high =  (end_session_condition == 0) and v_extend_high ==v_extend_high[1] ? color.green:na

plot(v_extend_low, color=col_v_extend_low, title="Extend Low")
plot(v_extend_high, color=col_v_extend_high, title="Extend High")
```

[image]

Comment: I am finding a hard time to understand _low and _high variables. Could you please help me understand it?

Comment: For `_low`, if it's a new session, start to plot the low, then plot the lowest point inside the session, vice versa for `high`

Comment: Thank you! Could you also please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735278/how-to-close-the-trade-at-the-end-of-the-day-if-i-took-a-position-in-the-same-da

Comment: I'll take a look, don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: Hi Edward, I need to create a strategy where if the market crosses those first highest high and lowest low. I need to enter whichever the market crosses those lines. Could you please help me on that?

Comment: I can't do it from scratch, you already have the core, from there, just use the `crossover(high, v_extend_high)` and `crossunder(low, v_extend_low)` to get the crosses, and from here you have basically everything and you can do/modify anything you want or need

Comment: Thank You Edward. It means a lot to me. I got the answer. God Bless you!

Comment: I want to enter the strategy after 30 points when market crosses high. For example : market crosses the highest high line at  360 and I want to enter long  at 390. Can I do that?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `crossover(high,  v_extend_high  +30)` and add `plot(v_extend_high + 30)` if you want to see it